# How do I escape reserved word column in postgres using rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I have an integer column named "length" under a shift_breaks table. Accessing the column through ruby works fine but when trying to query the column using `.where` won't return me the desired results..

I've tried various ways to bypass it but can't find a solution that doesn't involve renaming the column. Any help would be very much appreciated.

```
# Application details

Rails: 5.1.6.2
Ruby: 2.5.3
PostgreSQL: 9.6.10
```

[image]

Comment: Could you provide example of "query the column using .where" and the error message?

Comment: @PavelMikhailyuk - here's the query

```"SELECT \"shift_breaks\".* FROM \"shift_breaks\" WHERE \"shift_breaks\".\"shift_id\" = 1 AND \"shift_breaks\".\"length\" = 10"```

Answer (score 0):

`length` is not a reserved word in ruby and psql. check this link to know the reserved words in psql - [reserved words in postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/sql-keywords-appendix.html). Kindly post your `error` with the `where query`.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

This ended up being an issue in the model. A `before_validation` is calling a method with `write_attribute` - preventing the record from updating in the database... =_=

---

[image]

What the shift break w/ length 20 actually looks like on the database..